# Passing input to URL path parameter from variable - Python

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest, web-api-testing

Please someone let me know how I could send input to *URL path parameter* from a variable. I do have an idea on passing input to *Query Parameter* through payload but below API uses path parameter and I need to pass **8**, **3** and **+** as variables and I do not have an idea how I could pass them:

```
http://localhost:8184/messenger/webapi/Calculator/8/3/+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use string interpolation to build a URL. Do make sure you quote your values before putting them in the URL:

```
from urllib import quote

op1, op2, operator = '8', '3', '+'
url = 'http://localhost:8184/messenger/webapi/Calculator/{}/{}/{}'.format(
    quote(op1), quote(op2), quote(operator))
```